# php - regex/preg_match_all (child) shortcode attribute

Tags: php, arrays, regex, shortcode

I try to regex/preg_match_all shortcodes (in wordpress) in order to get a specific attribute value, however my php code partially works...

In fact I success to regex parent shortcodes but not children shortcodes.

My shortcode looks like to this:

```
[to_custom_font family="Lato;900italic" decoration="" style="normal"]Content[/to_custom_font]
```

Here my php code:

```
preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$post_content,$matches);
$to_shortcode = array_keys($matches[2],'to_custom_font');
if (!empty($to_shortcode)) {
    foreach($to_shortcode as $sc) {
        preg_match('/family="([^"]+)"/', $matches[3][$sc], $match);
        $font_infos = explode(';',$match[1]);
        $family     = $font_infos[0];
        $variant    = $font_infos[1];
        $font       = $family.':'.$variant;

        if(!in_array($font, $available_families)){
            $available_font = array_merge($available_font, array($font => $post_id));
        }

    }
}
```

It works with parent shortcodes but not with children shortcodes:

```
[to_custom_font family="Lato;900italic" decoration="" style="normal"]Content[/to_custom_font] //parent shortcode

[to_section attr="" attr3=""]
[to_custom_font family="Lato;900italic" decoration="" style="normal"]Content[/to_custom_font]//child shortcode
[/to_section]
```

It seems that the problem comes from here :

```
preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$post_content,$matches);
```

`$matches` only return parent shortcodes. And I need to get all children levels...

My aim with this code is to get all value `family=""` attribute. Maybe there is a better way to do it...

Comment: Your second `preg_match` should be `preg_macth_all` as well [http://regex101.com/r/mX9nR2/1](http://regex101.com/r/mX9nR2/1) Maybe I could suggest a better solution if I knew what's the $pattern in the first `preg_match`

Comment: Thnak you for your help. But When I get the first `preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$post_content,$matches);` I only get parents shortcode with `$matches[2]`...

Comment: Is this what your looking for [http://ideone.com/YkI03M](http://ideone.com/YkI03M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this might be what you need

```
$string = '[to_custom_font family="Lato;900italic" decoration="" style="normal"]Content[/to_custom_font] //parent shortcode[to_section attr="" attr3=""][to_custom_font family="Lato;900italic" decoration="" style="normal"]Content[/to_custom_font]//child shortcode[/to_section]';

preg_match_all('/family="([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);    
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match . "\n";
}

// or use print_r() to see the whole array

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Lato;900italic
Lato;900italic

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => family="Lato;900italic"
            [1] => family="Lato;900italic"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lato;900italic
            [1] => Lato;900italic
        )

)
```

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/YkI03M) | [Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/mX9nR2/1)

Comment: Thank you it works like this. Does it slow down to `preg_match_all` all the string? And also I need to be sure that it only get attribute from shortcode and not a string outside the shortcode...

Comment: @freaky No worries :) This is a simple expression so it would be done very fast. As you might saw, this will match only the font-family but if you have more complicated string (content), update your question, drop me a note here and I'll test it again ;)

Comment: @freaky Just to be more accurate, `preg_match()` stops capturing after the first match while the `preg_match_all()` continues until it finishes processing the entire string.

Comment: I just want to get `family` attribute inside shortcode in case if there is also `family=""` in body text outside the shortcode `[]`

Comment: @freaky As you might see, the snippet above does exactly that; if you face any difficulties drop me a note here.